# Eclipse PDT + PHP + XDebug + OpenShift

Tags: php, eclipse, openshift, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

How to get PHP xDebug work with OpenShift using Eclipse PDT?

I use [this](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/php/getting-started.html#development-mode) to make xDebug up on OpenShift PHP 5.4 application.

I've ssh tunneling turned on in PHP debugging options.

Once I have debugging started connection possible:

```
$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But breakpoints does not work.

How to make breakpoints work?